# Restore duplicati configuration from backup

Tags: restore, duplicati

I lost my system drive a day ago and with it all my duplicati settings/jobs (not the backups - they are ok)

Restoring works fine but I'd like to restore/recreate my jobs from an existing backup and continue backing up to that location

Is there a way to do that (couldn't find it in the web interface nor online documentation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created the job with the same settings (default settings and same AES password) and tried to start a backup, duplicati complained about a missing database and suggeted a db repair.

After the db repair run everything was back to normal.

Comment: i have a 12 Years old Duplicati backups. The Windows OS HDD is available. Is there a Chance to read password out of this Windows OS ? Or other Chance to read this 12 years old Data?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is (sadly am on mobile right now) try to find where duplicati stores its configuration and give it a look.